# Clojure - How to apply a different function to each column?

Tags: csv, vector, dictionary, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and playing with it for fun.

I'm reading a CSV file and want to apply a different function to each column. What is an elegant (both concise and readable) way to do this?
I have explored two approaches:

- **Working on a vector of rows:**

for each row...

```
(def row-1 ["John", "24"])
```

...I want to apply a different function to each element, and obtain this result:

```
["John", 24]
```

The function I want to use are:

```
(def converters-1 [identity, read-string])
```

Is there a simple way to apply the `converters-1` functions to the `row-1` elements?

- **Working on a map:**

With this method I start by turning each row into a map:

```
(def row-2 {:name "John", :age "24"})
```

Edit: And I want to obtain this map:

```
{:name "John", :age 24}
```

The converters are also stored in a map:

```
(def converters-2 {:name identity, :age read-string})
```

Is there a simple way to apply the right converters to the `row-2` elements?

I will be interested to read solutions for both approaches.

In the end I will put the data into a map. I'm just not sure whether I want to do the conversions before or after getting this map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` for sequences; use `merge-with` for maps.

```
user=> (map #(% %2) converters-1 row-1)
("John" 24)
user=> (merge-with #(% %2) converters-2 row-2)
{:name "John", :age 24}
```

Comment: `merge-with` for maps, brilliant! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
(map #(%1 %2) converters-1 row-1)
;; ("John" 24)
```

if `(def row-2 {:name "John", :age "24"})` (it's an integer in your example)

```
(for [x (keys converters-2)] ((converters-2 x) (row-2 x)))
;; ("John" 24)
```

Comment: Perfect, cheers! I hadn't realized that map can take more than two arguments, that's powerful.

Comment: For the map-approach solution, I forgot to mention that I want to obtain a map:

    (into {} (for [x (keys converters-2)] [x ((converters-2 x) (row-2 x))] ))

PS: I now modified my original question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the map approach, but it's less elegant than Diego's solution with vectors.

```
(into {} (map (fn [[k v]] 
    [k  ((converters-2 k) v)]
) row-2))
```

Is there a simpler solutions for this map-approach?
Am I missing a core function that would simplify it?

Edit: reading Diego's edit, I could also use `keys`:

```
(into {} (map #( 
    [%  ((converters-2 %) (row-2 %))]   ; the key, and the converted value
) (keys row-2)))
```

But I prefer the previous solution, because it does not need the comment: it is obvious what happens to the key, and to the value. Plus, in this solution I only need to write `row-2` once.

Edit 2: If I write `(converters-2 k identity)`, then I only need to indicate the columns who need a transformation. For the other columns (like `:name` here) `identity` is the default converter. That is an advantage, compared to the vector approach.

Edit 3: I found a another solution for the map approach, using `update-in`:

```
(reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] (converters-2 %2)) row-2 (keys row-2))
```

Well, now that it's written, to my novice eyes it's harder to read and understand.

So far the vector solution is still best. I'll keep my eyes open for a better map solution; it might come in handy some day.